# How do i receive the right Value

Tags: php, html, radio-button

The Counter wont go up. As you see should the Counter go up if the PHP Code receive the A Value.

html:

```
 <body>
    <div>
      <div>
         <h1>Login</h1>
         <form method="post" action="quiz.php">
         <input name="A" value="A" type="radio">
              <label for="A">A</label>
         <input name="A" value="B" type="radio">
              <label for="A">B</label>
         <input name="A" value="C" type="radio">
              <label for="A">C</label>
         <button id="submitbutton" 
     type="submit">Antworten</button>
    </form> 
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>


<?php
    if(!empty($_POST)) {
        if(!empty($_POST['A'])) {
            $counter = $counter + 1;
        }
    }
    echo $counter;

    ?>
```

Sometimes i get HTTP ERROR 412

Comment: you have to set `$counter` value to 0 (? I guess) before your ifs. Now it is undefined

Comment: $counter is set to 0. Forgot to add that. And $_POST should be checked with (!empty())

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. If the counter is set to 0 before the checks, then the counter can only be `0` (if you don't get the correct post data) or `1` (if you do) since it will reset the counter on each request. That could just as easily be checked in JS.

Comment: i still wont work